# Masonry jquery Plugin with lazyloading

Tags: jquery, lazy-loading, masonry

When using masonry with lazysizes, which lazyloads images, meaning it dynamically adds them to the grid, all added images that were not in the viewport do not fit in the grid as they should. They stacked. So I added a class to lazyload:

```
.lazyloading {
    opacity: 0;
    min-height: 350px;
```

But that doesn't solve the issue, since images have different heights, they overlap or have too much margin. When I resize the whole window even for just 1px, the images rearange themselves perfectly. I tried using imagesLoaded too, but it didn't help.

Test case:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EpmpaN

Comment: _“I tried using imagesLoaded too, but it didn't help”_ - right now, it causes an error in your pen. Fix at least that please, before you state that stuff “didn’t help” ... code that throws errors seldom ever does.

Comment: ImagesLoaded is not added to the pen. that is why it's causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

This temporarily solved my problem. It reactivates masonry when scrolling:

```
var $grid = $('.grid').masonry({
  itemSelector: '.grid-item',
  percentPosition: true,
  columnWidth: '.grid-sizer'
});
// layout Masonry after each image loads
$grid.imagesLoaded().progress( function() {
    $grid.masonry('layout');
});  
// scroll event to fire masonry
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > 300){
            $grid.masonry('layout');
        }
    });
});
```